# Will the Public ip addres change after changing the Router/Moderm

Tags: internet, isp

I wanted to know if the public IP address will change after changing the Router

(And is there a way to figure out the public IP on a Raspberrypi)

Thanks, Ananth

Comment: AFAIK your public IP will change, unless you've paid for a static IP (which isn't cheap) or you're using a 3rd party DNS service. Not posted as an answer as i'm not 110% sure on this.

Comment: The only answer is “depends.” Some ISPs give you the same IP address no matter what. Some assign different IP addresses on each reboot of a machine. Some change it for other reasons. Unless you explicitly pay for a static IP address, you should always assume the IP address will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the modem will typically restart your connection with the ISP.

The router part of your ISP device (if it's a modem/router combo), or most consumer routers if you have your own, separate router, will typically ask for an IP when it detects a disconnect/reconnect.  It typically uses DHCP for this purpose.

The ISP may give you the same IP you had before, or a different one.  It's only obligated to give you the same one if you are paying for a static IP.  Otherwise you might get the next free one in a pool.

> (And is there a way to figure out the public IP on a Raspberrypi)

Easiest, quickest way is to type "what is my IP" in a Google search if Internet access is working and you need a human-readable output.

You can also get this information by logging into your router's web interface, typically 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.50, 192.168.0.100 or 192.168.0.254 if you haven't changed any configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but sadly the sd card does not support raspbian(The full version) so i needed to go to the command line version Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

*Maybe.*

Unless you’re paying for it, you generally have a dynamic IP address. So there is no guarantee it will remain the same.

However, there is also no guarantee it will change. Maybe your IP address has a long lease time and is linked to your user account instead of, say, the modem’s MAC address or whatever.

---

There are many ways to figure out your public IP address. For example `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` or `curl ifconfig.me` or whatever. There’s even more web pages for this, which I will not list here.